# Proper way to show loading state before show DOM in React

Tags: reactjs, loading, state

I just want to know, what is the best way to show loading state before data that is being fetched by AJAX loaded. I've tried to reproduce it using setInterval on codepen. [Code](http://codepen.io/adrianhartanto/pen/MyPjaj)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isFetching: true,
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    let that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      that.setState({
        isFetching: false,
      });
    }, 2000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.isFetching ? 'Fetching' : 'Done'}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

React.render( <App / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: That's a good way to handle that situation, anyway you dont need "that" in your componentWillMount, just use "() =>" instead of "function()"

Comment: @QoP But it will raise a warning like this `Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.`
What is that mean?

Comment: it's because the component is not mounted yet so it has no state, just move the call to componentDidMount()

Comment: I've already moved that too into componentDidMount(), but its still raise the warning.... @QoP

Comment: that's weird, I modified your codepen and that warning does not show.

Comment: Hmm, can you try that code on your browser? Not in the codepen i mean, because the warning is not show up on codepen @QoP

Comment: Why not setState for isFetching: false in the callback of your AJAX request?

Comment: Already @EzraChang .. SetTimeout is just for mocking ajax request.. I call ajax inside componentDidMount/componentWillMount and then set isFetching into false when callback. Still raise the warning.